# How to match a comma separated cell to sum values from multiple rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, string-matching

I have been trying to take the value of one a cell: ("String 1", "String 2") and then search in another column for each instance of "String 1" and "String 2", and sum their output on column+1.

I included an image of what i'm trying to accomplish. I've tried index match, and sumif but have had no luck so far!

This is the text I want to reference:
[image: this is the text I want to reference]

(Call it A26)

This is where I want to search and find the matching text:

[image: This is where I want to search and find the matching text]

Essentially, I want to be able to pick any random combo of Schools, and then it will search my data for the matching schools and then sum the population.

I'd prefer not to uses VBA (thanks for reading! )

Answer (score 0):

**Where:**

- Each Row contains a unique string in Column A and a corresponding number in Column B
- Cell C1 contains any number of strings from Column A separated by a comma

> **This formula sums the corresponding values in Column B**
>
> `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A:A&",",C1&",")),B:B))`

---

***IMPORTANT NOTE:*** This is an array formula that **must** be entered with **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**  and it will be **{** *enclosed by curly brackets* **}** when entered correctly.

Comment: awesome, so I got this to work! The only thing is, I don't think this is too realistic for scalability. For example, if I wanted to do this for 30 strings it would be very time consuming and likely cause for human error

Comment: @Madatya Agreed.  Your example was not explicitly clear in that regard but you can blame my lack of sensibility.  I'll think about it some more and update the answer with a more scalable solution.

Comment: @Madatya Updated with an array formula.  As written, the formula tries to find a match in the entire column  (`A:A` and `B:B`), so you may want to constrain the range to your data size for faster performance (`A1:A45` and `B1:B45`).

Comment: My friend, this is as simple a solution as can be, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" is to split the comma-separated list into separate items.

If you have Excel 2013+, you can use:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A3,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),campusTbl,2,FALSE))
```

where `campusTbl` refers to the two column range where you have your population data.

*(There are other methods that can work in earlier versions)*

---

**EDIT:**

For example, if you don't have the `FILTERXML` function, try:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),campusTbl,2,FALSE),0))
```

where `seq_99` refers to:  `=IF(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,255,1))=1,1,(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,255,1))-1)*99)`

I used a Named Formula for `seq_99`

---

In some versions of Excel, you may need to confirm this formula by holding down ctrl+shift while hitting enter.

- We split the string by either

  - Create an XML from the comma-separated list
  - Extract each "node"
- Or by using the method shown in the second formula
- `VLOOKUP` will then return the population of the node and we can SUM them

[image]

Comment: So... I have a mac.. I should have mentioned that in the original post, which is why I could not use filterxml.

Comment: @MadatyaNersesian See my edit where I've posted another version which uses other functions to split the string, and should work on a MAC.

Comment: Thank you ! awesome response! Haven't thought of it in this context before.

Answer (score 0):

A formula solution using SUMPRODUCT+SUMIF+FILTRXML(), of which FILTERXML available in Excel 2013 or above.

In `E3`, enter formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(D3,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),B:B))
```

[image]

Comment: So your solution looks completely awesome and robust, however unfortunately it is not available on Excel for Mac (huge bummer). I am currently looking for a work-around with different function of filterxml